# Creating just one looping to make list - Shell

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I want to create a .xml file with an specific config, this config needs an hostname and ip, i have created the `hosts.csv` to input this data being them `vm-tmb-test1;127.0.0.1` on `.csv file` for each separator line `";"` is a hostname and ip of a server, but the looping i have created print for each ip in the hosts.csv

Code Structure

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in $(cat /var/projects/etc/hosts.csv | cut -d\; -f1)
do
    for ips in $(cat /var/projects/etc/hosts.csv | cut -d\; -f2)
    do
        if [[ ${i} == *"jua"* ]]
        then
            sed -i '$ a <node name="'${i}'" tags="infra,jua,vm" hostname="'${ips}'" username="test"/>' /var/projects/etc/resources.xml
        elif [[ ${i} == *"tmb"* ]]
        then
            sed -i '$ a <node name="'${i}'" tags="infra,tmb,vm" hostname="'${ips}'" username="tests"/>' /var/projects/etc/resources.xml 
        fi
    done
done
```

Host.csv content:

```
vm-tmb-test1;127.0.0.1
vm-tmb-test2;127.0.0.2
vm-tmb-test3;127.0.0.3
vm-jua-test4;127.0.0.4
```

Desired Output:

```
<node name="vm-tmb-test1" tags="infra,tmb,vm" hostname="127.0.0.1" username="test"/>
<node name="vm-tmb-test2" tags="infra,tmb,vm" hostname="127.0.0.2" username="test"/>
<node name="vm-tmb-test3" tags="infra,tmb,vm" hostname="127.0.0.3" username="test"/>
<node name="vm-jua-test4" tags="infra,jua,vm" hostname="127.0.0.4" username="test"/>
```

Actual Code Output:

```
<node name="vm-tmb-test1" tags="infra,tmb,vm" hostname="127.0.0.1" username="test"/>
<node name="vm-tmb-test1" tags="infra,tmb,vm" hostname="127.0.0.2" username="test"/>
<node name="vm-tmb-test1" tags="infra,tmb,vm" hostname="127.0.0.3" username="test"/>
<node name="vm-tmb-test1" tags="infra,tmb,vm" hostname="127.0.0.4" username="test"/>
<node name="vm-tmb-test2" tags="infra,tmb,vm" hostname="127.0.0.1" username="test"/>
<node name="vm-tmb-test2" tags="infra,tmb,vm" hostname="127.0.0.2" username="test"/>
<node name="vm-tmb-test2" tags="infra,tmb,vm" hostname="127.0.0.3" username="test"/>
<node name="vm-tmb-test2" tags="infra,tmb,vm" hostname="127.0.0.4" username="test"/>
```

How can i fix that?

Edit 1:
host.csv contains then more of 200 servers hostname and ip's it will be fed with time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While faster solutions (eg, `awk`, `sed`) exist, for this answer I'm going to stick with OP's idea of using a loop ...

Sample input:

```
$ cat host.csv
vm-tmb-test1;127.0.0.1
vm-tmb-test2;127.0.0.2
vm-tmb-test3;127.0.0.3
vm-jua-test4;127.0.0.4
```

Since the sample code appears to just be appending output to a `*.xml` file I'm going to opt for a single `while` loop that generates the desired output:

```
while IFS=";" read -r i ips                             # use ';' as input delimiter and read values into our 2 variables 'i' and 'ips'
do
        tag='UNDEFINED'                                 # define some defaults in case 'i' does not 
        uname='UNDEFINED'                               # have a match in our case statement

        case "${i}" in                                  # pattern match 'i' to determine what strings to submit to the printf command
                *jua*)  tag='jua' ; uname='test'   ;;
                *tmb*)  tag='tmb' ; uname='tests'  ;;
        esac

        printf '<node name="%s" tags="infra,%s,vm" hostname="%s" username="%s"/>\n' "${i}" "${tag}" "${ips}" "${uname}"

done < host.csv
```

The above generates:

```
<node name="vm-tmb-test1" tags="infra,tmb,vm" hostname="127.0.0.1" username="tests"/>
<node name="vm-tmb-test2" tags="infra,tmb,vm" hostname="127.0.0.2" username="tests"/>
<node name="vm-tmb-test3" tags="infra,tmb,vm" hostname="127.0.0.3" username="tests"/>
<node name="vm-jua-test4" tags="infra,jua,vm" hostname="127.0.0.4" username="test"/>
```

**NOTES**:

- OP can redirect the output of the `printf` to the final destination
- this should be a bit more efficient than repetitive `sed -i` calls
- I have copied OPs code snippet that shows the use of `username="{test|tests}"` (though OP's sample output only shows the string `test`); OP can edit the proposed code as needed

Answer (score 1):

A single GNU `sed` call could do the job:

```
sed -E 's/([^-]*)-([^-]*)-([^;]*);(.*)/<node name="\1-\2-\3" tags="infra,\2,\1" hostname="\4" username="test"\/>/' file
```

Comment: This not work for me, because the host.csv file contains then more of 200 server's hostname and ips, it will be fed with time.

Comment: @bmoreira18 Can you give an actual example why this should not work? I don't understand why the size of the file should be a problem.

Comment: @bmoreira18 I've tested it with your input sample and got the expected output. 200 records shouldn't be an issue at all.

Answer (score 1):

Pushing the `while` loop solution into a single `awk` call:

```
awk -F";" '                              # input delimiter is ";"
           { tag="UNDEFINED" }           # default tag in case $1 does not match the following patterns
$1 ~ /jua/ { tag="jua"       }
$1 ~ /tmb/ { tag="tmb"       }

           { printf "<node name=\"%s\" tags=\"infra,%s,vm\" hostname=\"%s\" username=\"test\"/>\n", $1, tag, $2 }
' host.csv
```

This generates:

```
<node name="vm-tmb-test1" tags="infra,tmb,vm" hostname="127.0.0.1" username="test"/>
<node name="vm-tmb-test2" tags="infra,tmb,vm" hostname="127.0.0.2" username="test"/>
<node name="vm-tmb-test3" tags="infra,tmb,vm" hostname="127.0.0.3" username="test"/>
<node name="vm-jua-test4" tags="infra,jua,vm" hostname="127.0.0.4" username="test"/>
```

**NOTES**:

- again, OP can redirect the output of the `printf` to the final output file (alternatively, direct the entire output of the `awk` call to said output file)
- for this answer I'm assuming all output should have the same string `username="test"`